# Installing mysql-community-devel on RHEL9, "Errors during downloading metadata for repository 'mysql80-community'"

Tags: rhel, mysql, dnf

This is my second instance where I am doing this installation and it is not working as expected...

```
dnf -y localinstall mysql80-community-release-el9-5.noarch.rpm
```

I installed mysql80-community-release-el9-5.noarch.rpm
Then I don't remember exactly but I think I was able to install mysql-community-devel at this point.
This is the command I wrote in my documentation:

```
dnf install mysql-community-devel.x86_64
```

My first instance is working fine, however...

On my second instance....

Installing mysql80-community-release-el9-5.noarch.rpm
and then trying to install mysql-community-devel ends in error.

Installing mysql80-community-release-el9-5.noarch.rpm on second instance:

```
dnf -y localinstall mysql80-community-release-el9-5.noarch.rpm
Updating Subscription Management repositories.
Red Hat Enterprise Linux 9 for x86_64 - AppStr 196 kB/s | 4.5 kB     00:00
Red Hat Enterprise Linux 9 for x86_64 - BaseOS 187 kB/s | 4.1 kB     00:00
Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 9 - x86_64 159 kB/s | 2.3 kB     00:00
Dependencies resolved.
===============================================================================
 Package                        Arch        Version    Repository         Size
===============================================================================
Installing:
 mysql80-community-release      noarch      el9-5      @commandline       13 k

Transaction Summary
===============================================================================
Install  1 Package

Total size: 13 k
Installed size: 12 k
Downloading Packages:
Running transaction check
Transaction check succeeded.
Running transaction test
Transaction test succeeded.
Running transaction
  Preparing        :                                                       1/1
  Installing       : mysql80-community-release-el9-5.noarch                1/1
  Verifying        : mysql80-community-release-el9-5.noarch                1/1
Installed products updated.
Errors during downloading metadata for repository 'mysql80-community':
  - Curl error (56): Failure when receiving data from the peer for http://repo.mysql.com/yum/mysql-8.0-community/el/9/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml [Recv failure: Connection reset by peer]

Installed:
  mysql80-community-release-el9-5.noarch

Complete!
```

Attempt mysql-community-devel on second instance:

```
dnf install mysql-community-devel.x86_64
Updating Subscription Management repositories.
MySQL 8.0 Community Server                     0.0  B/s |   0  B     00:00
Errors during downloading metadata for repository 'mysql80-community':
  - Curl error (56): Failure when receiving data from the peer for http://repo.mysql.com/yum/mysql-8.0-community/el/9/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml [Recv failure: Connection reset by peer]
Error: Failed to download metadata for repo 'mysql80-community': Cannot download repomd.xml: Cannot download repodata/repomd.xml: All mirrors were tried
```

I think I also tried as many mysql-devel name varieties as I could.

I have been stuck on this for a little while, and after a while I managed to figure out that I was missing the mysql-community-devel package on the second instance compared to the first.

I tried looking for logs of my user commands but was unable to find any helpful logs or history.

What am I missing....?

---

Update:
I tried downloading `mysql-community-devel-8.3.0-1.el9.x86_64.rpm`
and installing it, but I get similar issues...

```
dnf -y localinstall mysql-community-devel-8.3.0-1.el9.x86_64.rpm
Updating Subscription Management repositories.
MySQL 8.0 Community Server                     0.0  B/s |   0  B     00:00
Errors during downloading metadata for repository 'mysql80-community':
  - Curl error (56): Failure when receiving data from the peer for http://repo.mysql.com/yum/mysql-8.0-community/el/9/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml [Recv failure: Connection reset by peer]
Error: Failed to download metadata for repo 'mysql80-community': Cannot download repomd.xml: Cannot download repodata/repomd.xml: All mirrors were tried
```

I was expecting it to look for `mysql80-community` locally instead of thru the internet because `mysql80-community` is already installed through `mysql80-community-release-el9-5.noarch.rpm`

```
dnf repolist enabled | grep mysql
mysql-connectors-community   MySQL Connectors Community
mysql-tools-community        MySQL Tools Community
mysql80-community            MySQL 8.0 Community Server
```

Answer (score 3):

Apparently your network connection to the `repo.mysql.com` is not exactly stable: something keeps interrupting connections to it every now and then.

It might be that you just had the bad luck to try and connect to `repo.mysql.com` just when they were updating the server or doing some other maintenance, or perhaps something in the path between your system and the server caused the connection to be broken.

You might try `sudo traceroute -T -p 80 repo.mysql.com` to perhaps find out where the connections are getting broken. If the fault seems to be within the first three or so hops, and your system is at home/small business, you might try resetting your router/modem. If the fault is further away, or the system to which you are trying to install MySQL is a cloud service, then you might want to see if your internet service provider/cloud provider has posted an fault/outage notice.

Comment: I have stable internet and I highly doubt their server is having issues because I tried yesterday and today.
more likely that its getting blocked or something than instability... hmm

is internet needed to install the devel package? since I am local installing the mysql package anyway

Comment: Still, the `Recv failure: Connection reset by peer` means something at the remote side of the connection actively terminated it with a TCP Reset packet. It might have been the remote server, or a firewall-like device somewhere in-between. You may have a stable connection to your Internet Service Provider, but perhaps the connection between it and Akamai (the Content Delivery Network hosting `repo.mysql.com`) is overloaded?

Comment: Because you are using `dnf install`, the package management is trying to fetch the most up-to-date package from the remote repository. If you have the `mysql-community-devel*.rpm` package available locally, use `dnf localinstall mysql-community-devel*.rpm` to install it.

Comment: ah... okay. I thought the devel package was able to be pulled from the mysql80-community-release-el9-5.noarch.rpm repo... I'm guessing not

Comment: I just tried localling installing the mysql-community-devel and got similar issues.....

Comment: The `mysql80-community-release-el9-5.noarch.rpm` is less then 15 kB in size. It contains only the repository configuration files for `/etc/yum.repos.d/` and the GPG public keys for verifying the signatures of packages downloaded from `repo.mysql.com`. While you have this problem, you might want to move the `/etc/yum.repos.d/mysql-community*.repo` files out of that directory, or otherwise disable the repositories defined in those files, to stop the package management from trying to fetch the repository metadata for them.

Comment: I tried disabling the repos from `mysql80-community-release-el9-5.noarch.rpm`, and then installing `mysql-community-devel-8.3.0-1.el9.x86_64.rpm` gives errors about it missing mysql-community-libs and libmysqlclient.so.

Comment: Apparently the `mysql-community-devel` package depends on `mysql-community-libs` (the `libmsqlclient.so` library is in that package too), and `dnf` was trying to automatically fetch it from `repo.mysql.com` for you. The `-libs` package in turn depends on `mysql-community-common` and `mysql-community-client-plugins`.

Comment: thank you for your time! i found the solution. Network related